Determining the zeros and poles of a common emitter amplifier
I want to determine the transfer function of the base common emitter amplifier. I don't want to neglect the impedances of the capacitors in the calculations because I want to determine the zeros and poles of the amplifier.
I can determine the transfer function, but it is very complicated (even more complicated with emitter degeneration and capacitor). What do you recommend for a simpler solution? How could this problem be solved? I tried MathCAD but unfortunately it couldn't display the result because it's too big.
Here is the circuit and the small-signal model:

And here are the formulas:


FACTs analysis?

Is it not sufficient for you to know the relevant time constants only?

@LvW: It might be enough. Could you explain this further?

As highlighted by Antonio51, the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs are the ones you need here, especially if you account for all capacitors: this is a 4th-order system. You have a double zero at the origin and four poles. You could simplify your schematic by grouping (paralleling) resistances in the left side but also in the right side. If time permits, I can have a look later in the day if you wish.

@slimcolt: The time constant T=1/wo gives the 3dB-corner frequency for a highpass resp. lowpass function. This time constant is nothing else than the product of the corresponding C  and the connected equivalent resistance combination.

@Verbal Kint: Yes, I would love it! I would like to understand how I could solve the problem with the FACT technique.

@LvW Thank you for your help!

I have gone through the derivation of the transfer function of this transistor-based amplifier, including the dc-block capacitors and the two parasitic contributors. Needless to say that without the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs, it would be a nightmare to get to the result that I obtained without writing a single line of algebra, just inspecting small sketches.
You start by determining the gain at dc, for \$s = 0\$, and then turn the input source off to obtain all the time constants. There are four capacitors with individual state variables which means a fourth-order transfer function:

It looks intimidating but it's not, just carefully draw these little sketches with proper labeling and they will help you fix a wrong time constant if necessary. This is the cool thing here: if you spot a deviation between what you obtain with the FACTs and the brute-force transfer function, not need to restart from scratch. Just identify the guilty sketch, fix the associated time constant and there you go.

For the zeroes, I have chosen the generalized formula which means I have to determine high-frequency gains. As it is usually the case, many of these gains are zeroed by the shorting of capacitors across the signal path so, in the end, only one remains:

Once you have these contributors, assemble them and check the magnitude and phase response between all the transfer functions. In the end, the difference in magnitude and phase between the brute-force expression and the FACTs should be in the solver noise, at the pico level. This is what I have here:

This is how the FACTs lead you to the results here, in this 4th-order circuit. Further work would be necessary - further factoring this expression - but I'm done for the day : ) If you are interested by the approach, I invite you to take a look at my last book on the subject.

Omg! Thanks for the detailed answer! ;) It's completely understandable and really doesn't require hardcore algebraic equations (that was my basic problem). Tomorrow I will also calculate with this method and add an emitter resistor and a capacitor. I managed to find a mistake in my drawing! :D Thank you!

With pleasure! If you want to start learning FACTs, I would suggest you start with simple examples, like those in my APEC 2016 seminar for instance.
